# Special Characters in Grafana Variable Causing "no data" Output in Query

Tags: grafana, special-characters, grafana-loki, grafana-variable, grafana-dashboard

I've encountered an odd interaction in my Grafana dashboard where I'm storing a specific string in a variable called errorMsg. The string is: ERROR: DoorBoard: SetErrorClass[Uart]: Open /dev/ttyUSB2 Exception: Access to the port '/dev/ttyUSB2' is denied.

When I insert this string directly into my query, it works as expected and returns data.
Note that for demonstration purposes, I put $errorMsg in the title of the dashboard to show that it is getting interpreted correctly. However, the characters ' seem to be problematic when inserting into the regex:
[image]

When I copy the exact same variable (as shown in the Dashboard Title) in place of the $errorMsg, I get the expected output:
[image]

As explained above, the difference seems to be in the characters '. When I try the same with messages without these characters, I don't have any issues.

Another Example:
[image]
[image]

I've attempted to escape the special characters in the errorMsg variable, but still encounter the "no data" output. I expected the query to work the same way whether the error message string is inserted directly or referenced through the variable.

Comment: Can you inspect query in the panel, and show how query looks after variable substitution?

Comment: Nevermind, just checked myself: Grafana quotes `'` in variables with ``\\`` (at least for loki). To avoid this use `${variable:raw}` or `${variable:text}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{job="systemd-journal"} |~ `${errorMsg:raw}` works as markalex suggested